# Routing rules in cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, routes, amazon-cloudfront

I have routing rule set up for my static site in S3; however, it seems that cloudfront doesn't abide by these same rules. It at the very least doesn't obey the index file rule.

Is there anyway to set up routing similar to s3 in cloudfront? Is there a more powerful routing solution?

Comment: Having the same problem. It's pretty annoying that it doesn't abide by the rules. I would assume that s3 would just send a redirect based off the routing rules...but it seems to bypass.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was pointing cloudfront to the S3 bucket as opposed to the static domain name. If you point directly to the S3 bucket, the routing rules are bypassed (which makes sense since your routing rules are set only on the static hosting). Create a custom origin to the static public S3 bucket website and you're good.

I direct you to this answer on ServerFault: [Why S3 website redirect location is not followed by CloudFront?](https://serverfault.com/q/450940)

Comment: I didn't succeed to get it to work until I've set the CloudFront behavior to forward the "Accept" header. Without the header I was receiving empty file download.

Comment: Switching from the bucket endpoint to the bucket _website_ endpoint was the fix for me, thank you! Note for others: in the CloudFront console, the Origin Domain drop down is _also_ text input, so you can just paste in your bucket's website endpoint.